# Get bounds of featureGroup with multiple features

Tags: leaflet, geojson, boundaries

I tried looking into a solution for this myself, or an alternative way to load my layers, but I'm simply unable to.

I first load a geoJSON file through L.GeoJSON.AJAX(), then add the features (polylines and markers) that I need to a L.featureGroup(), but I'm having issues using the featureGroup.getBounds() function when doing this.

How can I get the bounds of all the features added to a featureGroup like this?

**Edit:**
Added code. Completely slipped my mind when asking the question to include this.

```
function addMapData(id, map) {
  var newIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: './img/icons/ring.png',
    iconSize: [84, 80],
    iconAnchor: [5, 70],
    popupAnchor: [10, 10],
  });

  var mapData = L.featureGroup();

  new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('./data/fjelltrimmen/fjelltrimmen.vefsn.geojson', {
    local: true,
    style: {
      weight: 5,
      color: '#c0392b',
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      if (feature.properties.id === id) {
        // Polyline
        layer.addTo(mapData);

        // Map marker
        L.marker([
          feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][1],
          feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][0],
        ], { icon: newIcon }).addTo(mapData);
      }
    }
  });

  mapData.addTo(map);
  map.fitBounds(mapData.getBounds());   
}
```

Comment: Can you share your full code as well?

Comment: @whyzar Sorry about that, absolutely slipped my mind the first time around. Updated the post with my function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44880792/map-fitbounds-with-json-data-in-a-featuregroup/44979020#44979020

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ghybs pointed me to a link and I eventually came to realise that the fitBounds function was outside the main call, however that didn't completely solve my problem.

After looking closer at the geoJSON.Ajax plugin, I came across 3 different events you could subscribe to. One of the events is
`data:loaded`

My function ended up becoming like this, and it's working wonderfully even with larger geoJson files (Mine is ~800mb for example):

```
function addMapData(id, map) {
  var newIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: './img/icons/ring.png',
    iconSize: [84, 80],
    iconAnchor: [5, 70],
    popupAnchor: [10, 10],
  });

  var mapData = L.featureGroup();

  var tracks = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('./data/fjelltrimmen/fjelltrimmen.vefsn.geojson', {
    local: true,
    style: {
      weight: 5,
      color: '#c0392b',
    },
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      if (feature.properties.id === id) {
        // Polyline
        layer.addTo(mapData);

        // Map marker
        L.marker([
          feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][1],
          feature.geometry.coordinates[feature.geometry.coordinates.length - 1][0],
        ], { icon: newIcon }).addTo(mapData);
      }
    }
  });

  mapData.addTo(map);

  tracks.on('data:loaded', function () {
      map.fitBounds(layers.getBounds());
  });
}
```

Comment: In the end you write "map.fitBounds(layers.getBounds());", but "layers" is never defined in your code, so what is this variable?

Comment: Ok, I think the idea is just to have another feature group that has ALL of the markers (don't add it to the map, just use it to get the bounds).